# Javascript function scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to call an instance method a() from within a jQuery ajax call. But when I do so, it says that the method is not defined. I think it's because a() is not within the scope of $. But I thought it would be part of the scope chain. How can a() be within scope?

```
function Z() {
    this.x = 0
    this.a = function() {
      return this.x;   
    }
    this.b = function() {
        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                this.a(); //a() is not defined
            },
            ...
        }); 
    }  
}

z = new Z();
z.b();
```

Comment: Try alerting `this`.  You'll find it is not what you expect.

Comment: This question, or something very similar, is asked about 10 times a day. Can someone *please* add an FAQ type answer (or two) to the jQuery documentation so that such questions can simply be directed there? Or if such exists, please post the links - frequently!! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other solutions will almost certainly work, but there's an even slicker, more idiomatic, way to do this with jQuery: use the [`context` option with `$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax):

> #### context
>
> This object will be made the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By default, the context is an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call (`$.ajaxSettings` merged with the settings passed to `$.ajax`).

---

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    context: this,
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        this.a(); //a() is now defined :)
    },
    ...
});
```

Comment: Even the self-proclamed Ninja's a jQuery misunderstand "context". Why isn't the option called *bind*, because that's what it emulates. It could even be called *this* (but would then need to be in quotes which would probably be seen as confusing - oh well).

Comment: A function's *this* keyword has nothing at all to do with either the calling or execution context. Nothing, nada, zilch. Quite the opposite in fact - an execution context has a *this* parameter that is set before any code is executed in that context. It is controlled completely by the calling code (or *bind* in ES5). It can even be *undefined* (ES5 strict mode) or *null*.

Comment: Okay, so trying to respond clear, 5 minutes after waking up, was a poor idea. Let me try again: you're right that `this` is not exactly the same as the execution context. But, since every execution context contains a `ThisBinding` component (ECMA-262 §10.3: _"The value associated with the `this` keyword within ECMAScript code associated with this execution context."_), the `this` value is 1-to-1 with execution context. It's a reasonable jump to use "context" as a shorthand for `ThisBinding`, especially since _"it is impossible for an ECMAScript program to access an execution context."_

Comment: Additionally, `bind` in this context (no pun intended) is a verb, not a noun, so if anything, I'd argue that `bindTo` would be a better name for that `$.ajax()` option.

Answer (score 3):

Most people will suggest a trick like `var that = this;`, but I prefer using function binding to achieve the same end more elegantly and clearly.

Create a local function `a`, which is `this.a` bound to `this`:

```
function Z() {
    this.x = 0
    this.a = function() {
      return this.x;   
    }
    this.b = function() {
        var a = this.a.bind(this);
        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                a();
            },
            ...
        }); 
    }  
}

z = new Z();
z.b();
```

Comment: While there's obviously more than one way to skin this cat, there's [a more idiomatic way to do this with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155750/javascript-function-scope/7155783#7155783).

Comment: What if you want access to both objects?

Comment: What do you mean, "both?" Which two objects?

Comment: The instance of `Z`, as well as the `this` object normally presented in the callback?

Comment: If this were an actual requirement, [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) would do quite nicely.

Answer (score 2):

No "that" trick, change the [context of the ajax callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
            context: this,
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                this.a(); //a() is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function Z() {
    var that=this;
    this.x = 0
    this.a = function() {
      return that.x;   
    }
    this.b = function() {
        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                that.a(); //a() is not defined
            },
            ...
        }); 
    }  
}

z = new Z();
z.b();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can not use 'this' in the callback function.

```
function Z() {
var that=this;
this.x = 0
this.a = function() {
  return this.x;   
}
this.b = function() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            that.a(); //a() is not defined
        },
        ...
    }); 
}  }
```

Comment: [Sure you can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155750/javascript-function-scope/7155783#7155783).

Answer (score 0):

`var that=this;` use `that.a`. The `this` is not available from inner function/object, you have to use `that=this` trick.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the jQuery Ajax object when you call `this.a()`. You need to do something like this:

```
function Z() {
    this.x = 0
    this.a = function() {
      return this.x;   
    }
    this.b = function() {
        var that = this;
        $.ajax({
            ...
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                that.a(); //a() is not defined
            },
            ...
        }); 
    }  
}

z = new Z();
z.b();
```